# Apache - RewriteCond/RewriteRule for URL in HTTPS and with a specific parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to add a parameter to the URL if the URL is being accessed in **https** and only if the parameter doesnt already exists (I don't need to check the parameter value).

1. Example 1: nothing should be done because the url is being accessed in http

   Original URL: http://example.com
   Final URL: http://example.com
2. Example 2: Apache needs to redirect to https://example.com?parameterName=parameterValue

   Original URL: https://example.com
   Final URL: https://example.com?parameterName=parameterValue
3. Example 3: Nothing should be done because the url is in https and contains the parameter "parameterName" (this one is to prevent infinite loop)

   Original URL: https://example.com?parameterName=parameterValue
   Final URL: https://example.com?parameterName=parameterValue

What I've tried so far :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^parameterName$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}%parameterName=parameterValue
```

Edit 1: If I remove the "RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on" condition it seems the rule is being executed. The parameters are not being appended correctly but at least the rule is being executed.

Now I need to understand why the rule is not being executed when in HTTPS.

Googling a bit I found some posts saying that the AllowOverride has to be changed to AllowOverride All.

I updated the line below in my httpd-conf file but the behaviour did not change:

From:     AllowOverride **None**
  To to    AllowOverride **All**

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond: _“REQUEST_URI -
The path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html". This notably excludes the query string which is available as its own variable named QUERY_STRING.”_

Comment: And you want to put a `?` in front of the parameter name in your substitution URL, not a `%` as you are currently doing.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe! I changed REQUEST_URI to QUERY_STRING and corrected the rewrite rule and now it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below did what I needed:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*parameterName.*
RewriteRule /myapplicationpath?(.*) /myapplicationpath?parameterName=parameterValue&%{QUERY_STRING} [R]
```